# Is it possible to navigate to a dynamic page in Exrin

Tags: exrin

Is it possible in Exrin to push to the navigation a contentpage I create in run time and afterwards remove it from the navigation stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't possible at the moment, as you have to define the type, to create the navigation mapping.

If you wanted to look into a PR to do this, would be happy to accept this PR. It would involve creating a new method to navigate to an IView. Would also have to think about how it interacts with Stacks.